# NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/events/CustomEvent on call to createJeuclidDom

Tags: java, netbeans, mathml

I'm learning to use jeuclid-core-3.1.9 in java using the Netbeans development platform with Maven. All dependencies were generated automatically by Netbeans based on the imports in the source code.

I tried to create a MathML tree from the DOM I created from a MathML formula contained as a string in my program. However, the code below encounters the exception NoClassDefFoundError on the call to createJeuclidDOM. The missing class is
org/w3c/dom/events/CustomEvent. This class appears in the Projects window as part of package org.w3c.dom.events in the batik-ext-1.7 jar file. However, when you select the class, nothing shows up in the Navigator window, suggesting it's not really there. I suspect I'm up against a compatibility issue, but I can't imagine what it is.

The source code:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 */

package com.mycompany.jeuclidtrial;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import net.sourceforge.jeuclid.parser.Parser;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import net.sourceforge.jeuclid.DOMBuilder;
import net.sourceforge.jeuclid.elements.generic.DocumentElement;
import net.sourceforge.jeuclid.swing.JMathComponent;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 *
 * @author Tony
 */
public class JeuclidTrial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String formula;
        
        formula = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
        formula += "<math mode=\"content\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">";
        formula += "<apply><power/><apply><plus/><ci>a</ci><ci>b</ci><ci>c</ci></apply><cn>2</cn></apply>";
        formula += "</math>";

        try {
            /**
             * This code adapted from
             * https://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/index.html
             */
            
            StringReader aStreamReader = new StringReader(formula);
            StreamSource aStreamSource = new StreamSource(aStreamReader);
            Parser aParser = Parser.getInstance();
            Document theDocument  = aParser.parseStreamSource(aStreamSource);
            DOMBuilder dBuilder = net.sourceforge.jeuclid.DOMBuilder.getInstance();
            DocumentElement theDocumentElement = dBuilder.createJeuclidDom(theDocument);
            JMathComponent theMathComponent = new JMathComponent();
            theMathComponent.setDocument(theDocumentElement);
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        
        
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The stack trace follows:

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/events/CustomEvent
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3297)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField0(Class.java:3482)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:2115)
    at net.sourceforge.jeuclid.elements.JEuclidElementFactory.addClass(JEuclidElementFactory.java:146)
    at net.sourceforge.jeuclid.elements.JEuclidElementFactory.<clinit>(JEuclidElementFactory.java:186)
    at net.sourceforge.jeuclid.elements.generic.DocumentElement.createElementNS(DocumentElement.java:165)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.startElement(SAX2DOM.java:159)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.closeStartTag(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:206)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToSAXHandler.flushPending(ToSAXHandler.java:250)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.startElement(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:648)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.startElement(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:510)
    at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa.http$colon$$slash$$slash$www$dot$w3$dot$org$slash$1998$slash$Math$slash$MathML$colon$template$dot$34()
    at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa.applyTemplates()
    at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa.http$colon$$slash$$slash$www$dot$w3$dot$org$slash$1998$slash$Math$slash$MathML$colon$template$dot$206()
    at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa.applyTemplates()
    at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa.http$colon$$slash$$slash$www$dot$w3$dot$org$slash$1998$slash$Math$slash$MathML$colon$template$dot$0()
    at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa.applyTemplates()
    at jdk.translet/die.verwandlung.GregorSamsa.transform()
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.AbstractTranslet.transform(AbstractTranslet.java:627)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:782)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:395)
    at net.sourceforge.jeuclid.DOMBuilder.applyTransform(DOMBuilder.java:217)
    at net.sourceforge.jeuclid.DOMBuilder.createJeuclidDom(DOMBuilder.java:202)
    at net.sourceforge.jeuclid.DOMBuilder.createJeuclidDom(DOMBuilder.java:155)
    at net.sourceforge.jeuclid.DOMBuilder.createJeuclidDom(DOMBuilder.java:135)
    at com.mycompany.jeuclidtrial.JeuclidTrial.main(JeuclidTrial.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.events.CustomEvent
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 27 more
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

After this printout, the log from a failed build occurs:

```
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  7.466 s
Finished at: 2023-09-05T09:33:22-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) on project jeuclidTrial: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Show the stack trace. Also describe how you created the project in enough detail so that others can attempt to reproduce the problem. That includes the type of the project (Maven/Grade/Ant), and how you obtained the external resources (Batik, JEuclid, etc.).